# integrating google map api 3 and using javascript on android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an android application that will integrate map from google maps api 3. I've read this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3) and can't understand what this block of codes does.

```
private void setupWebView(){
  final String centerURL = "javascript:centerAt(" +
  mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + "," +
  mostRecentLocation.getLongitude()+ ")";
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  //Wait for the page to load then send the location information
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
      webView.loadUrl(centerURL);
    }
  });
  webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);
}
```

Can somebody explain to me thoroughly what this codes do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Late, but maybe it will help someone else.

I am not quite sure since I am a beginner, but my guess is you are calling a JavaScript function called "centerAt", take a look to this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3, you will see the JavaScript bridge definition with that function "centerAt"

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var latitude = 0;
    var longitude = 0;
    if (window.android){
      latitude = window.android.getLatitude();
      longitude = window.android.getLongitude();
    }
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  }
  function centerAt(latitude, longitude){
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    map.panTo(myLatlng);
  }
  </script>
```

To sum up, what you are really doing is displaying a map in an Android app using a JavaScript bridge, so from the Android code you use the JavaScript functions defined on it, calling them trough an URL.

Again, I am beginner (frist day with Google Maps), probably I am wrong.